# UIScrollView content size out of bounds in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, uiscrollview

I have a wired bug in **iOS7**, my `UIScrollView` content height is out of screen bounds and I can't scroll down to the bottom.

I'm using AutoLayout.

The view heirarchy is:

```
- UIView
 - UIScrollView
  - UIView
   - Buttons
```

In **iOS8+** it's working fine.

I have this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets)]) {
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

And this also:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1380);
}
```

Comment: try self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1380); inthis 1380 place set your control height +50

Comment: Can you not scroll at all, or is it just cutting off short? Also, are you using xibs or storyboard?

Comment: A screenshot would make this more understandable

Comment: The bottom is cut off, but it's not 64pts it's a lot more.. I'm using storyboard... lets say if the screen height is 1380, I can see only 300.

Comment: May I see the code where you set frame of the scrollView. If you are developping  for iPad and working on a landscape  app. It could be the screen's bounds that make your scrollview's frame wrong. If so, check Uiscreen class Refrence: the second paragraph.

Comment: The app is Portrait and iPhone only.